Is there a way to specify feature names in PyOD?
I usually save my models with the 'pickle' library in python, and I know how to set my feature's names in other libraries,
Example: For CatBoost, I can set my feature names here:
https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_set_feature_names
So that the next time I load the CatBoost model, I'll know what features were used in training the model.
However, I couldn't find a similar thing in PyOD? Does anyone know how to do this?
I've read up some documentations on PyOD:
https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyod.models.html#
Yet, the 'get_params' and 'set_params' functions were referring to scikitlearn's documentation here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html
It did mention about 'feature name validation', but there were no examples on how to do so.
Many thanks!
